# Show that either $x$ or $1-x$ is invertible in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field, and let $R$ be a subring of $F$. Suppose that for each $u\in F\setminus \{0\}$, either $u\in R$ or $u^{-1}\in R$. Given $x\in R$, show that either $x$ or $1-x$ is invertible (or unit) in $R$.

For local ring, I could imagine but not the above case.

Comment: The rings with the property you mentioned are called *valuation rings* and they are local.

Comment: $\!\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad  u\, :=\, 1-x^{-1}\in R\  &&{\rm or}\,\ \  (1-x)^{-1}\!-1\! \,=\, u^{-1} \in R\\
\iff\quad x^{-1}\in R\  &&{\rm or}\,\ \ (1-x)^{-1}\in R
\end{eqnarray}\quad $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $u:=\frac{x}{1-x}$. If $u$ is in $R$ then $1+u$ is in $R$. But $(1-x)(1+u)=1-x+x=1$, so $1-x$ is invertible.

If $u$ is not in $R$ then $u^{-1}$ is in $R$. Use now $1+u^{-1}$ as above. We get that $1+u^{-1}$ is in $R$. But $x(1+u^{-1})=x+(1-x)=1$. Hence $x$ is invertible.